# Sum All Document Keys Dynamically

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following structure of my document :

```
{"x":1, "y":1}
```

where the keys are unknown and dynamic. I want to a result which aggregates all the fields. 
Example : 
If my collection consists of :

```
{"x":1, "y":10}
{"x":1, "y":20}
{"x":2 , "z":13}
```

I want result to be

```
{"sum":{"x":4, "y":30,"z":13}
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MongoDB 3.6 you can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to split the objects apart and accumulate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
        "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this.k", "_id" ] }
      }
    }
 }},
 { "$unwind": "$data" },
 { "$group": {
   "_id": "$data.k",
   "v": { "$sum": "$data.v" }
 }},
 { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
 { "$group": {
   "_id": null,
   "data": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$v" } }
 }},
 { "$replaceRoot": { 
   "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
 }}
])
```

Returns:

```
{ "x" : 4, "y" : 30, "z" : 13 }
```

And the same thing basically with `mapReduce()` if you don't have a MongoDB supporting those operators:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    var doc = this;
    delete doc._id;
    emit(null, doc);
  },
  function(key,values) {
    var output = {};
    values.forEach(value =>
      Object.keys(value).forEach(k => {
        if (!output.hasOwnProperty(k))
          output[k] = 0;
        output[k] = output[k] + value[k];
      })
    );
    return output;
  },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Slightly different, mapReduce style output:

```
    {
            "_id" : null,
            "value" : {
                    "x" : 4,
                    "y" : 30,
                    "z" : 13
            }
    }
```

Comment: What if the data is nested like { "metricData":{"x":1}} ?

Comment: @user2810114 If it's ALL in there then you just point at that field instead of the `$$ROOT` and anything else that is discarding `_id`. But if you still cannot work it out then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Once you ask a question, that's it. You don't get to keep asking more questions in comments since that is not how it works here. You state clearly an concisely in your question what you need to do and what you have tried. And you don't decide to change that when someone has answered you either. Play nice and we be nice.

Comment: Sorry, it worked when i made  "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT.metricData" } . Thanks a lot.